# FileSystemWatcher and GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, filesystemwatcher

I have a little problem with my WPF project and the FileSystemWatcher class.
In my MainWindow class the watcher begins to watch a folder when Button Start is clicked in the UI.
Everything works without any problems - the watcher recognizes correctly when a file is created. 
But while watcher is waiting it is not possible for user to do anything in the UI. It should be possible for nexample to click Stop...

```
 private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rdbTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        Start.IsEnabled = false;
        rdbTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Test gestarte-Warte auf Befund....")));
        Stop.IsEnabled = true;

        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(ConfigSettings.Default.FilePath); 

        // Only watch text files.
        // watcher.Filter = "*.bef";
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
        // Add event handlers.          
        watcher.Created += OnCreated;
        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait until new file in folder
        watcher.WaitForChanged(System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created);           
        watcher.Dispose();

        // Parse letter
        edifactLetter = parser.ParseDocument(ConfigSettings.Default.FilePath + "\\" + fileName);
        // Validate Letter
        edifactVal.Validate(edifactLetter);

        writeResults();
        Start.IsEnabled = true;           
    }

    private void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {   
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        fileName = file.Name;
    }
```

Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: As an aside: methods of `parseDocument` and `validate` aren't conventional - they should be `ParseDocument` and `Validate`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `WaitForChanged()` is not an asynchronous method, it is synchronous. Meaning if you are using that in your UI thread it will get blocked.

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67220zhk(v=vs.110).aspx

I suggest that you could create an event handler for the `OnChanged` event and then do what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [`WaitForChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67220zhk(v=vs.110).aspx) is a synchronous method:

> This method waits indefinitely until the first change occurs and then returns.

You're calling that from the UI thread - therefore blocking any other UI thread interaction in the meantime. You don't want to do that.

You should probably just listen for the appropriate events - calling your parsing/validation methods in the event handler. You should also make sure you do all UI work in the UI thread, but ideally as little *other* work as possible... so unless the parsing and validation needs to interact with the UI, do it in a different thread.

Comment: great and quick response

Answer (score -3):

You can mark method `async` and put long running task into a task. Don't forget prevent another call while first one is running:

```
private async void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    button.Enabled = false;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        .. long running task here will not block UI
    });
    button.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: To downvoter, yes, I know it's not the right way to deal specifically with filewatcher (because it may never trigger, thus halt forever), but it's a general idea of not blocking UI for a task which will finish at some point.