# powershell: change GUI element when async FileSystemWatcher fires

Tags: powershell, user-interface, filesystemwatcher

I like to change a GUI element (windows-form in powershell ISE), when a new file is created. Therefore I set up a form and start a filesystemwatcher in another runspace (MWE):

```
# this function should be called when a new file is created
function foobar(){
    $form.BackColor = "black"
}

# set up runspace for async FileSystemWatcher
$Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$PowerShell = [System.Management.Automation.PowerShell]::Create()
$PowerShell.runspace = $Runspace
$Runspace.Open()

[void]$PowerShell.AddScript({
    $logFile = 'C:\powershell\test.log'  
    $dirName = 'C:\powershell\'

    $hotFolder = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $dirName -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}
    Register-ObjectEvent $hotFolder Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
          $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
          $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath 
          $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
          $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

          Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"

      # this call does not work
      foobar
      }  
})

$AsyncObject = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()

# set up form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.ShowDialog()
```

The FileSystemWatcher works (log-file is written), but the call of "foobar" is ignored / does not work.

My first try was to Register the FileSystemWatcher within the form, which does not work (similar to this: [FileSystemWatcher and GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783356/filesystemwatcher-and-gui?rq=1)). I found this thread  [FileSystemWatcher kommt nicht mit Form zurecht (german only)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/de-DE/ca22b471-5f6f-4b3e-856c-4131c5fadc77/filesystemwatcher-kommt-nicht-mit-form-zurecht?forum=powershell_de), which suggests the use of runspaces.

The runspace solves the stuck GUI-problem, but I need a way to trigger events in the form, when the fileSystemWatcher registers a new file. How can I achive that?

in short:

1) how can the FileSystemWatcher trigger a change of a GUI-element

2) are runspaces the right approach in this case

I'm not an expert in powershell (still learning). Any help and suggestions  are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found a solution:

- added a synchronized hashtable to share variables between runspaces
- added a button of the form to the hashtable (this button will be hidden in the final version drawing.Size(0,0) )
- fileSystemWatcher makes use of performclick() to click the button
- button calls desired function on click

There is still a point which feel awkward:

- to unregister the fileSystemWatcher I set a shared variable to 1 and trigger the fileSystemWatcher by generating a file

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Do I miss some points where the code is unnecessarily complicated?

Any comments are appreciated.

Here is a MWE. To use it set the $dir variable to your need. (MWE does not work in not updated powershell which ships with Win7)

```
# set working dir
$dir = 'C:\Downloads'
Write-Host 'working dir' $dir


# create function which is called when new file is created
function showPath($path){
  $label.Text = $path
}

# set up runspace for async FileSystemWatcher
$Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$Runspace.Open()

# synchronized hashtable and hashtable elements
$sync = [Hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
  $sync.path = 1  # random start value
  $sync.exit = 0  # switch: if set to 1 fileSystemWatcher will be unregistert when next event occurs
  $sync.dir = $dir

  $btnNewFile= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $btnNewFile.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(220,10)
  $btnNewFile.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,23)
  $btnNewFile.Text = "do not click - fake button"
  $btnNewFile.Add_Click({
    $newPath = $sync.path
    $form.text = $newPath
    showPath($newPath)
  })

  $sync.btnNewFile = $btnNewFile

$Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("sync", $sync)

$PowerShell = [System.Management.Automation.PowerShell]::Create()
$PowerShell.runspace = $Runspace

[void]$PowerShell.AddScript({
    $logFile = Join-Path $sync.dir test.log  
    $dirName = $sync.dir

    $hotFolder = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $dirName -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}
    Register-ObjectEvent $hotFolder Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
          $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath 
          $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
          $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
          $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

          # check if exit condition is met
          if($sync.exit -eq 1){
            Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append -InputObject "Exit file: '$name'"
            Unregister-Event FileCreated
          }
          else{
          Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"

          # set path to synchroniszed variable
          $sync.path = $path

          # click Button to trigger function call
          $sync.btnNewFile.PerformClick() 
          }

      }
})

$AsyncObject = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()

# GUI setup
$labelHeader = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$labelHeader.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,50)
$labelHeader.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23)
$labelHeader.Text = 'path to new file:'

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,50)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,23)
$label.Text = 'no file created'


$global:fileCounter = 0
$btnCreateFile = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnCreateFile.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$btnCreateFile.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23)
$btnCreateFile.Text = "New File"
$btnCreateFile.Add_Click({
  $global:fileCounter+=1
  $fileName = "$global:fileCounter.txt"
  $newFile = Join-Path $dir $fileName
  New-Item $newFile -ItemType file
})

$btnExit = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnExit.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,10)
$btnExit.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23)
$btnExit.Text = "&Exit"
$btnExit.Add_Click({
  $sync.Exit = 1
  $btnCreateFile.PerformClick() 
  $Powershell.Dispose()
  $form.Close()
})

# set up form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Width = 400
$form.Height = 120
$form.Controls.Add($btnCreateFile)
$form.Controls.Add($btnExit)
$form.Controls.Add($labelHeader)
$form.Controls.Add($label)
$form.Controls.Add($sync.btnNewFile)

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like your solution, but the problem, like you say, is not working for PS2.0, including the service pack 1 for Win7, where I need.

My solution for the GUI update works both in PS2(win7) and in PS3(win10), it is based in Windows Presentation Framework(WPF) instead Windows Forms, because with WPF we can use [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-wpf) and the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) interface. I have based my work in Trevor Jones web [How-To](https://smsagent.blog/2017/02/03/powershell-deepdive-wpf-data-binding-and-inotifypropertychanged/) ,with some tricks to get work.

For your question about Unregister the system I have translated, from VB to PS, a post from Mike Ober in [SpiceWorks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1953495-filesystemwatcher-subdirectories?page=1#entry-6518801), in which his concept to Register and Unregister the system based in global variables and possible errors inspired me.

Here is my code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework,PresentationCore,WindowsBase

Function Create-WPFWindow {
    Param($Hash)
    # Create a window object
    $Window = New-Object System.Windows.Window
    $Window.Width = '600'
    $Window.Height = '300'
    $Window.Title = 'WPF-CONTROL'
    $window.WindowStartupLocation = [System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation]::CenterScreen
    $Window.ResizeMode = [System.Windows.ResizeMode]::NoResize

    # Create a Label object
    $Label = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.Label
    $Label.Height = 40
    $Label.HorizontalContentAlignment = 'Left'
    $Label.VerticalContentAlignment = 'Center'
    $Label.FontSize = 15
    $Label.Content = 'Actividad:'
    $Hash.Label = $Label

    # Create a TextBlock object
    $TextBlock = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
    $TextBlock.Height = 150
    $TextBlock.FontSize = 20
    $TextBlock.TextWrapping = 'Wrap'
    $Hash.TextBlock = $TextBlock

    # Create a Button1 object
    $Button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.Button
    $Button1.Width = 300
    $Button1.Height = 35
    $Button1.HorizontalContentAlignment = 'Center'
    $Button1.VerticalContentAlignment = 'Center'
    $Button1.FontSize = 20
    $Button1.Content = 'Iniciar'
    $Hash.Button1 = $Button1

    # Assemble the window
    $StackPanel1 = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel
    $StackPanel1.Margin = '150,20,5,5'
    $StackPanel1.Orientation = 'Horizontal'
    $StackPanel1.Children.Add($Button1)
    $StackPanel2 = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel
    $StackPanel2.Margin = '5,5,5,5'
    $StackPanel2.Orientation = 'Vertical'
    $StackPanel2.Children.Add($Label)
    $StackPanel2.Children.Add($TextBlock)
    $StackPanel = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel
    $StackPanel.Margin = '5,5,5,5'
    $StackPanel.Children.Add($StackPanel1)
    $StackPanel.Children.Add($StackPanel2)
    $Window.Content =  $StackPanel

    # Stop the service and release the resources
    $Window.Add_Closing({
        $Hash.On = $false
        $global:p.BeginInvoke()
        $global:p.Dispose()})
    $Hash.Window = $Window
}

$Hash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
# Create a WPF window and add it to a Hash table
Create-WPFWindow $Hash | Out-Null

# Create a datacontext for the TextBlock, we add it to the synchronized $Hash to update the GUI from the FileSystemWatcher Event.
$DataContext = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Object]
$Text = [string]'Pulse el botón para iniciar el sistema.'
$DataContext.Add($Text)
$Hash.TextBlock.DataContext = $DataContext
$Hash.DataContext = $DataContext
$Hash.path='C:\POWERSHELL_PROJECT\Result'
# These two vars are for my needs, you can obviate them or delete
$Hash.urlLOGIN=''
$Hash.urlLOTE=''
$Hash.fileWatcher = $null
$Hash.LOG='C:\POWERSHELL_PROJECT\Result\LOG.log'
$Hash.firstEvent = $false
$Hash.On=$false
$Hash.msg=''

# Create and set a binding on the TextBlock object
$Binding = New-Object System.Windows.Data.Binding -ArgumentList '[0]'
$Binding.Mode = [System.Windows.Data.BindingMode]::OneWay
[void][System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations]::SetBinding($Hash.TextBlock,[System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock]::TextProperty, $Binding)
# Add an event for the Button1 click to Register FileSystemWatcher and Unregister it
$Hash.Button1.Add_Click({
    if ($Hash.On -eq $true){ 
        $Hash.On = $false
        $Hash.Button1.Background = 'Green'
        $Hash.Button1.Content = 'Iniciar'
    }else{ 
        $Hash.On = $true
        $Hash.Button1.Background = 'Red'
        $Hash.Button1.Content = 'Detener'
    }
    $p.BeginInvoke() | Out-Null
})

# Multithreading runspaces for FileSystemWatcher
$rs_dForm = [Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
$rs_dForm.ApartmentState = 'STA'
$rs_dForm.ThreadOptions = 'ReuseThread'
$rs_dForm.Open()
$rs_dForm.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('Hash', $Hash)

$p = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
        Function global:OnFileSystemWatcherError {
            FileEventListener -Path $Hash.path
        }
        # With simple function we can refresh the Textbox and Log
        Function global:Refresh-WPF-and-LOG {
            $Hash.DataContext[0] = $Hash.msg
            echo $Hash.msg >> $Hash.LOG
        }
        Function global:FileEventListener ($Path){
            if ($Hash.On){
                $Hash.fileWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
                $Hash.fileWatcher.Path = $Path
                $Hash.fileWatcher.Filter = '*.xml'
                $Hash.fileWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
                $Hash.fileWatcher.InternalBufferSize = 32768
                $Hash.fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents=$true
                Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Hash.fileWatcher -EventName Changed -SourceIdentifier File.Changed -Action {
                    $Global:t = $event
                    if (!$Hash.firstEvent){
                        try{
                            # For example you can:
                            $Hash.msg = '[' + $(Get-Date -Format u | foreach {$_ -replace ' ','-'}).ToString() + ']--' + $event.SourceEventArgs.Name
                        }catch{
                            $Hash.msg = '[' + $(Get-Date -Format u | foreach {$_ -replace ' ','-'}).ToString() + ']--' + $_.Exception.Message + ' ' + $_.Exception.ItemName
                        }finally{
                            Refresh-WPF-and-LOG
                        }
                        $Hash.firstEvent=$true
                    }else{
                        $Hash.firstEvent=$false
                    }
                }
                # With this Register we control the errors from the FileSystemWatcher system, and reinit it this case
                Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Hash.fileWatcher -EventName Error -SourceIdentifier File.Error -Action {
                    $Global:t = $event
                    $Hash.On = $false
                    OnFileSystemWatcherError
                }
                $Hash.msg = '[' + $(Get-Date -Format u | foreach {$_ -replace ' ','-'}).ToString() + ']--' + 'Servicio INICIADO.'
            }else{
                if ( $Hash.fileWatcher -ne $null ){
                    $Hash.fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents=$false
                    Unregister-Event File.Changed
                    Unregister-Event File.Error
                    $Hash.fileWatcher.Dispose()
                    $Hash.fileWatcher=$null
                    $Hash.msg='[' + $(Get-Date -Format u | foreach {$_ -replace ' ','-'}).ToString() + ']--' + 'Sistema DETENIDO.'
                }
            }
            Refresh-WPF-and-LOG
        }
        FileEventListener -Path $Hash.path
})

$p.Runspace = $rs_dForm
# Show the window
$Hash.Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

I hope to help.